# Get column names of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I get a dataframe from an interface whith cryptically named columns, of which I know some substrings which are mutually exclusive over all columns.

An simplified example looks like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'d10432first34sf':[1,2,3],'d10432second34sf':[4,5,6]})
df
   d10432first34sf  d10432second34sf
0                1                 4
1                2                 5
2                3                 6
```

Since I know the column substrings, I can access individual columns in the following way:

```
df.filter(like='first')
   d10432first34sf
0                1
1                2
2                3

df.filter(like='second')
   d10432second34sf
0                 4
1                 5
2                 6
```

But now, I also need to get the exact column name of each column, which are unknown to me. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.columns`:

```
cols = df.filter(like='first').columns
print (cols)
Index(['d10432first34sf'], dtype='object')
```

Or better [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('first')]
print (cols)
Index(['d10432first34sf'], dtype='object')
```

**Timings** are not same:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'d10432first34sf':[1,2,3],'d10432second34sf':[4,5,6]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = df.columns + pd.Series(range(10000 * 2)).astype('str')

print (df.shape)
(3000, 20000)

In [267]: %timeit df.filter(like='first').columns
10 loops, best of 3: 117 ms per loop

In [268]: %timeit df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('first')]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: I think the second method will be much faster for bigger DataFrames with lots of __rows__

Comment: @MaxU - Good idea, I am going to test it.